# Error SQL[HY000] Error 1205 with import_products

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, magento-1.9.2

I have a problem with a job which manage import products and customers every night.

Randomly return an error when import products from SAP.

[image: Error products]

If u see the picture u can see the material **"SB-FHA125A-F_ASLV"** which was imported rightly but the product **"SB-FBA125A-F_GLY"** return an error when try to modify the **attribute sap_model**.

I mustn't modify the value of timeout in InnoDB.

Any idea about what is the problem?.

Thanks!

Comment: It could be helpful to log all deadlocks, see [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87350/view-last-several-innodb-deadlocks) on DBA on how to do it. That could help identify the thread that does the locking and leads to the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` file.

If you are using xampp you can find the `php.ini` file in location `xampp\php\php.ini`

after change in file save it and restart the server.

Comment: Sorry but i don't want increase the max_execution_time because this process is very slow now and don't like increase it